# What is the outcome for the arithemic in C?

Tags: c

There is an interview question in C as below.

```
int main()
{
   unsigned int a = 9;
   a = ~a;
   printf("%d\n", a);

}
```

I though it was supposed to be 6 but it is -10.
~a is assinged back to an unsigned integer then printed out.
It should not be a negative value.
Isn't it? Hoe come?

Comment: What was your method for getting 6?

Comment: You know the difference between `%d` and `%u`? Doesn't matter what the type of `a` is, it's interpreted matching the format specifier.

Comment: `%d` is for signed numbers. Use `%u` for unsigned.

Comment: `~` does a bitwise NOT, so every bit that was `0` becomes `1` and vice-versa, so the result is basically the largest possible number that can be stored in an `unsigned int`, minus `9`. It's definitively not 6.

Comment: By the way the largest possible number that can be stored in an `unsigned int`, if print as `signed`, is `-1`, hence why you got `-10`.